# Thread with background Process is not calling in parrallel

Tags: c#, multithreading

In my application I am using Multi Threading with background process but the method is calling by thread one by one.

For an example Thread 1 is calling first and then the thread 2. Please find below my code:

```
for (int x = 0; x < TotalThread; x++) 
{
    if (x == TotalThread - 1) limit = limit + reminder;
    List < NumberList > _Elements = nList.GetRange(offset, limit);
    Threads[x] = new Thread(() = > ProcessSMSBody(_Elements));
    Threads[x].IsBackground = true;
    Threads[x].Name = string.Format("MyThread{0}", x);
    offset = offset + limit;
    Threads[x].Start();
}
```

Then it is calling the Process SMS body which code is below:

```
private void ProcessSMSBody(List < NumberList > slsList) 
{
    string number, id, msg = "";
    if (slsList.Count > 0) 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < slsList.Count; i++) 
        {
            locker.WaitOne();
            SrcNumberList rec = new SrcNumberList();
            Invoke(new Action(() = > rec = LowCountNumber()));
            Random rnd = new Random();
            number = rec.SrcNumber;
            id = rec.SrcNumberId;
            Invoke(new Action(() = > msg = spintax(rnd, txtMSG.Text, slsList[i].Name.ToString())));
            //MessageBox.Show(msg);
            Invoke(new Action(() = > IsendSMS(number, slsList[i].Phone.ToString(), msg, id)));
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    }
}
```

All the process is completing one by one....any suggestion please..

Comment: What is this line `locker.WaitOne();` good for? You tell your threads to wait on something, maybe that's why they wait on something?

Comment: This code doesn't look at all right. What is `Invoke()`? Is it `Control.Invoke()`?

Comment: @MatthewWatson is correct, your "threaded" code is delegating almost every line back to your UI thread... that way, there is not much left for the thread to do but wait on the one thread that does all.

Comment: Why are you calling `new Random()` in a tight loop? You'll get non-random numbers.

Comment: Ah, is that why you have the `Thread.Sleep(100)`?

Comment: In my form I need to do a functionality Pause and resume. So, I have used     locker.Waitone(); 

I am new in threading can you please let me know the way that how I will use background thread by which I will be able to use the threading parallel. I do not want that next thread will wait for the current thread. Please suggest and thanks to all of you for giving feedback.

Comment: new Random() is using for generating the different SMS body I think that is not a big issue. The main issue with my code is thread is executing one by one like for loop.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the above comments.  I suggest rewriting to use [Data Parallelism](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537608(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
using System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel;

Parallel.ForEach(nlist, e => ProcessSMSBody(e));

void ProcessSMSBody(X sms)
{
   // do the work
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to all, I have fixed this issue...Actually, I was invoking the process and it was calling the method one by one. So, what I did I simply create object and called by thread. Now, it is calling parallel and thread is working properly.